# VBA MS Access query - return greatest date from linked table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, greatest-n-per-group

I have looked throughout the greatest-n-per-group tag and found great information but nothing that solves my specific problem.

Table A stores chemical data about all materials used.
It has fields such as RMCode, TradeName, Hazardous, DangerousGood (all **TEXT**)

Table B contains all the material safety data sheets (which are updated at least every 5 years), and we store superceded documents.
The fields are RMCode (**TEXT**), linkMSDS (**HYPERLINK**) and MSDSdate (**DATE/TIME**).
LinkMSDS is hyperlink to the pdf and we store the date of issue in MSDSdate. One RM code can have many attached MSDSs.

The two tables are linked through the field 'RM Code.'

I want to generate a list of all materials which are DangerousGoods - but I want only the most recent MSDS to be presented.
The code below is currently returning all MSDSs.

> SELECT tableB.[RMCode], tableA.[TradeName], tableA.[Hazardous], tableA.[DangerousGood], tableB.[link MSDS]
>
> FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.[RM Code]=tableB.[RM code]
>
> WHERE tableA.[DangerousGood] <> "N/A" and tableB.[MSDSdate] In
>
> > > (SELECT MAX(tableB.[MSDSdate])
> > >
> > > FROM tableB
> > >
> > > GROUP BY tableB.[RMCode])
>
> ORDER BY tableB.[RMCode];

Comment: I suspect the answer is easy...once we understand the question. Please consider re-reading it and make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks @iDevlop. Hopefully the changes have made it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need the latest MSDSdate for each RMCode.

```
SELECT RMCode, Max(MSDSdate) AS MaxOfMSDSdate
FROM TableB
GROUP BY RMCode;
```

If that's correct, you can use it as a suquery joined to TableA and add in the WHERE clause to exclude the rows with DangerousGood = "N/A".

```
SELECT a.RMCode, a.DangerousGood, b.MaxOfMSDSdate
FROM
    TableA AS a
    INNER JOIN [
        SELECT RMCode, Max(MSDSdate) AS MaxOfMSDSdate
        FROM TableB
        GROUP BY RMCode
        ]. AS b
       ON a.RMCode = b.RMCode
WHERE (((a.DangerousGood)<>"N/A"));
```

Finally, if you need the linkMSDS values for each of those RMCode/MSDSdate combinations, you can join another copy of TableB.

```
SELECT a.RMCode, a.DangerousGood, b.MaxOfMSDSdate, b2.linkMSDS
FROM
    (TableA AS a
    INNER JOIN [
        SELECT RMCode, Max(MSDSdate) AS MaxOfMSDSdate
        FROM TableB
        GROUP BY RMCode
        ]. AS b
        ON a.RMCode = b.RMCode)
    INNER JOIN TableB AS b2
        ON (b.RMCode = b2.RMCode) AND (b.MaxOfMSDSdate = b2.MSDSdate)
WHERE (((a.DangerousGood)<>"N/A"));
```

Comment: @Denbigh: if you enter the query above in Access, you will have to change `[...].` into `(..)`. Every time you save the query, Access changes the parenthesis surrounding the subquery, but strangely does not Accept those square brackets when you try to save them.

Comment: @iDevlop thanks for prompting me to fix the question statement (also the brackets tip)